# RhoMobile initial database

Tags: database, rhomobile

Is there a way to setup initial data in a database when using RhoMobile framework?
It is using sqlite database as I see. Is there a way to add a preset sqlite file to the project and make it built in the application bundle?

Comment: Please follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631406/create-seed-data-in-rhomobile/13320316#13320316) for recent changes and exact answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seed the database with a flat file containing the initial data, through the use of the `Rho::RhoUtils.load_offline_data` method. Full documentation [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/rhom#seeding-the-database).

Comment: Great, I'm thinking of doing exactly the same thing. My question is, at what point do you use the load_offline_data method so the seeded database is available when the application is built?