# Including a pre-seeded database in a RhoMobile application?

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, rhomobile, rhodes

So I'm planning on using the `Rho::RhoUtils.load_offline_data` method to seed my application's database as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836527/rhomobile-initial-database)

What I'd like to know is where I should call this method? Ideally, I'd like the seeded database to be available when the application is built. So rather than seeding the db the first time the application is for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's designed to be used in the [AppApplication initialize method](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/application#appapplication-class)